# PHP strtotime fails for 1 digit minute or second

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp, strtotime

php `strtotime()` failing, for one digit of minute or second.

for e.g-

```
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime('02/23/2013 8:50:1 PM'));  // 01/01/1970 01:00:00
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime('02/23/2013 8:5 PM'));     // 01/01/1970 01:00:00
```

Is there a **quick** solution for that?

I know, we can split it & check for minute or second string length, and add a 0 prefix.

By the way, one strange thing is, if the **last part** is one digit, it fails

for e.g-

```
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime('02/23/2013 8:5:10 PM'));  // 02/23/2013 20:05:10
// worked well, despite of one digit minute
```

Comment: I would always suggest `DateTime::createFromFormat()` instead of `strtotime()`. However in this case even that won't help you, because it also insist on leading zeros for minutes and seconds. It does seem a bit weird not to have them. Where are you getting those broken date/time strings from anyway? Can't you just enforce a better quality of input data?

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP Date Man Page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) states that the specifiers *i* and *s* for the date formatting command must contain leading zeros.

There's no way around this, they must contain the zeros.

Comment: true, but isnt it interesting that they do not have built in parameters for minutes and seconds without leading zero like they have  with hour,day ... ?

Comment: It could be misinterpreted whether the digit should have a leading or appended zero.  Whereas with hour/day/month etc. it is well known that a single digit should be prepended with a zero.  A single digit minute could be interpreted to be in the either place value column.

Comment: well when ppl write 8:5 h it usually mean then 8:05 with leading zero,  and in 90% or more cases if they wanted to write 8:50 it was a typo

Comment: I would see it as the vast majority of the time being a typo for 8:50, I've never seen 8:5h or even 08:5h written.  I assume there just isn't point for adding the possibility for this formatting when it seems to be against the "standard" of writing dates.

Comment: If anything, I think you're more likely to see decimal notation (it's 8.83~ am apparently). If it's really necessary though, you can always parse the string yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = '02/23/2013 8:5 PM';
$time = preg_replace('/ ([0-9]*:[0-9]) /', " \${1}0 ", $time );
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($time));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace_callback('/ ([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9]*)/', function($p){                                        
 return " ".str_pad($p[1], 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT).":".str_pad($p[2],2 , 0, STR_PAD_LEFT).":".str_pad($p[3],2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
},  $some_bad_date_string);
```

This will convert "11/04/2021 6:5:0" to "11/04/2021 06:05:00".